# Scaling labels at the same proportion with pictures in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm learning Tikz. I draw a picture with some labels and I want to insert it in my thesis. But I would like to scale it if it is big. Scaling pictures is not scaling the labels. I can apply a scaling factor to labels, but I prefer to scale everything at once, as we do in figure environment.

In the output you see `S/R1` remain the same after scaling

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,decorations,decorations.text, mindmap,shadings,patterns,matrix,arrows.meta,intersections,automata,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    coord/.style = {help lines, color=gray!40, dashed,xstep=0.5cm,ystep=0.5cm},%
    2ndRect/.style = {magenta, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=magenta},%
    3rdRect/.style = {magenta, pattern=crosshatch dots, pattern color=gray},%
    insideArrow/.style = {black,{stealth[scale=2]}-{stealth[scale=2]}},%
    smallRect/.style = {fill=white},%
    every node/.append style = {font =\bfseries},%
    scale=.5
    ]
%
% Draw HelpLines just to work faster
%
    \tkzInit[xmax=20,ymax=10,xmin=0,ymin=0]
    \tkzAxeXY
    \draw[coord] (0,0) grid (20,10);

%
% Draw Rectangles
%
    \draw (1,1) rectangle (18,5);                       % 1st rectangle
    \draw[2ndRect] (4,1.5) rectangle (15,4.5);          % 2nd rectangle
    \path[fill=white](6,2) rectangle (13,4);            % workaround 4 clipping background
    \draw[3rdRect] (6,2) rectangle (13,4);              % 3rd rectangle
    \draw[smallRect] (6.5,2.5) rectangle (8.5,3.5);     % small %rectangle
    \node at (7.5,3) {S/R1};                            % label
    \draw[smallRect] (10.5,2.5) rectangle (12.5,3.5);   % small rectangle
    \node at (11.5,3) {S/R1};                           % label
    \draw[insideArrow] (8.8,3) -- (10.2,3);             % arrow btwen small rectangles
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

##### Output with .5 scaling

[image: Scaling]

Comment: You can add `transform shape` to the `tikzpicture` options: `\begin{tikzpicture}[..., transform shape]`.

Answer (score 1):

One  solution could be to write `S/R1` in a `scalebox`, ie replacing lines 29 and 31 in your example by :

```latex
\node at (11.5,3) {\scalebox{0.5}{S/R1}};                           % label
```

So the text is also scaled with a `0.5` factor :

[image]

**NB :** the problem with this solution is that if you want to rescale to another factor, you would have to change on multiple lines the value, what I usually to is to define a macro

```latex
\def\scl{0.5}
```

outside the `tikzpicture` environment, and use the macro `\scl` anywhere I need it.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to change or input multiple macro where I need. `[transform shape]` is a good solution for me, as I stated, in my description. I, although, appreciate your answer!